# Better Way to Create an Audit Trail Using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, audit, change-tracking

I have looked through many examples of creating an audit trail using the Entity Framework and have yet to find anything that works for me.  There must be a slick/terse way to do it by simply overriding SaveChanges in the DB Context and using the ChangeTracker...issues I have run into are things such as when adding (creating) an entity it does not have an ID until after you save it and when you save it, it seems to blast what's in the change tracker.  Anyway, I have got an audit trail working but it's ugly as hell and I was looking for help in simplifying this and making it such that I don't have to add on to a horrible if-then every time I add an entity!  Any and all help appreciated.

```
    public bool CreateRecord(object o)
    {
        Audit audit = new Audit()
        {
            ChangeTypeID = (int)Audit.ChangeType.CREATE,
            TimeStamp = GetCurrentDateTime(),
            RecordClass = o.GetType().ToString(),
            NewValue = "",
            ReasonForChange = "Record Creation"
        };

        if (o.GetType() == typeof(Permission))
        {
            Permission x = (Permission)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Permissions.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(User))
        {
            User x = (User)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Users.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(LogIn))
        {
            LogIn x = (LogIn)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            LogIns.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Marker))
        {
            Marker x = (Marker)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Markers.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Method))
        {
            Method x = (Method)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Methods.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Sample))
        {
            Sample x = (Sample)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Samples.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(Run))
        {
            Run x = (Run)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            Runs.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(XYDataSet))
        {
            XYDataSet x = (XYDataSet)o;
            audit.OriginalValue = x.ToString();
            XYDataSets.Add(x);
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Save audit record
        audit.UserID = ((App)Application.Current).GetCurrentUserID();
        Audits.Add(audit);
        SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: For something more generic, You could try [`Audit.NET`](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#auditnet) with its [EntityFramework extension](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#auditentityframework).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all of the entities belongs to same project/assembly, so you can try something like that and notice that this code doesn't tested, modifications might be needed.

```
    public bool CreateRecord(object o)
    {
        Audit audit = new Audit()
        {
            ChangeTypeID = (int)Audit.ChangeType.CREATE,
            TimeStamp = GetCurrentDateTime(),
            RecordClass = o.GetType().ToString(),
            NewValue = "",
            ReasonForChange = "Record Creation"
        };
        var entityType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Permission)).GetTypes().Where(x => x == o.GetType())
            .FirstOrDefault(); // Determine the desired entity (assumed all of the entities belongs to same project/assembly)
        if (entityType != null)
        {
            var convertedObject = Convert.ChangeType(o, entityType); // Convert object to entity
            audit.OriginalValue = convertedObject.ToString();
            var entity = yourContext.Set(entityType).Add(convertedObject); // Get DbSet for casted entity
            SaveChanges();
            audit.RecordID = x.ID;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Save audit record
        audit.UserID = ((App)Application.Current).GetCurrentUserID();
        Audits.Add(audit);
        SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much!  That got me 90% of the way there.  The only issue is that in each of my entities I have a primary key of ID.  In your code above you left my vestigial (now undeclared) x variable "audit.RecordID = x.ID".  Basically I am saving the type of the entity and the primary key ID such that I can get back to any entity from the audit trail.  So my follow up question is how do we pull the ID from the converted object?  (Again, thank you soooo much for your help!!!)

Comment: You're welcome. Would you try like this ? "var id = entityType.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(convertedObject, null);"